# Web Analytics Options with Hourly Hits Report

Tags: google-analytics-api, outlook-web-app, matomo

Currently we are using Piwik for analytics. I've looked into other available options and other two good candidates are Open Web Analytics and Google Analytics.

Piwik is doing fine but it doesn't provides hourly hits reports. Is there a way we write a wrapper to fetch hourly reports?

Our application (RoR) may have thousands of Pages to be tracked as separate websites. So going with Google analytics may be a problem at some stage due it's account/profile/hits limitations.

Please advise which one is the best suitable for above scenario, i.e. hourly hits reports and unlimited websites and hits.

Thanks,

Imran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piwik actually provides hourly reports, [see the hourly report in the demo](http://demo.piwik.org/index.php?module=CoreHome&action=index&idSite=1&period=day&date=yesterday#module=VisitTime&action=index&idSite=1&period=day&date=yesterday).

or [the API for hourly reports](http://demo.piwik.org/index.php?module=API&method=VisitTime.getVisitInformationPerServerTime&format=XML&idSite=1&period=day&date=yesterday&filter_limit=100).

But it doesn't provide ALL reports for each hour, because it would be too costly performance wise I think!